# Django Sitemap for multiple domain and same site

Tags: django, apache2, subdomain, sitemap, django-contrib

I have a Django website with a domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) hosted on a VPS. The same Website can be accessed from different domains like [www.example.xyz](http://www.example.xyz) and [www.example.one](http://www.example.one)

I already made a sitemap for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) which is working well. Using Django contrib sitemap function.

But now the problem is how to generate the sitemap for [www.example.xyz](http://www.example.xyz) and [www.example.one](http://www.example.one).

Sitemap from [www.example.xyz](http://www.example.xyz) and [www.example.one](http://www.example.one) shows me a link to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Comment: You could generate 3 sitemaps for 3 domains and in server(nginx, apache...) Point it to correct one based on hostname

Comment: I couldn't found any resource for multiple website sitemaps. Could you share some resources to do multiple website?

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391151/django-sitemap-change-base-url